# Laravel 4: What is the correct way to display data in a view?

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4

Let me explain myself better.

For example, I have a page that does only one thing: it displays the username in a big nice font.

What is the correct way, and by "correct way" I mean the way that respects MVC, to implement that?

I thought that directly calling a method inside a model wouldn't respect MVC pattern, but calling a method of a controller through a new GET/POST request to the server would be kind of a waste because on more complex pages I should make too many calls.

I also read about the [Laravel's View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) but even after reading its documentation I'm still quite unsure about how that should be implemented.

If possible, in addition to my previous question, can I a have a simple example to help me understand better?

Comment: can you please explain it more. I didn't get why it is a waste to call a controller function

Comment: You are already using laravel .. so what's the point of even pretending that you "respect MVC" ?

Comment: That doesn't mean that since I'm using Laravel everything I do is OK. I don't think that directly calling a model method inside a view respect the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is the way you send information from your controller to your view:

Let's say you have a route that expects the user id via GET (HTTP REQUEST method):

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'PagesController@showUserName');
```

It points to an action in your CONTROLLER (`app/controllers/PagesController.php`) that gets information from a repository (MODEL?) and sends to your VIEW:

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function showUserName($id)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->getUserById($user_id);

        return View::make('userNamePage')->with('userName', $user->name);
    }

}
```

And your VIEW (`app/views/userNamePage.blade.php`) just showing a big user name:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <h1>{{$userName}}</h1>
@stop
```

The way you get the information to send to your view is entirely up to you, but you should not put too much login in your controller nor in the view, that's why I am using a repository, but you will see a lot of people taking information directly from the MODEL, which is acceptable for small applications:

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
```

or

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I got a clearer picture of Laravel and the MVC pattern :) Have a nice day/night!